# Sinatra doesn't want to say hello

Tags: ruby, sinatra, vagrant-windows

What could possibly be wrong? I run this file:

```ruby
require 'sinatra' 
get '/' do 
  "Just Do It" 
end
```

Server starts up:

```
== Sinatra (v2.0.0) has taken the stage on 3000 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.7.1 codename Muffin Mode)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 127.0.0.1:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

(I set the address and port because it is what I have in my vagrantfile.

However I get nothing, either in Chrome or Firefox.  I've tried various config.ru's and changed the file above to an ru extension to try `rackup` but that hasn't worked either.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the Mustermann and Sinatra gems and made sure I had the gems that are required in `base.rb`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work outside of vagrant?

Comment: Using the 0.0.0.0 binding seemed to make a slight difference if i run the code with ruby.  I can then see the Sinatra 'welcome' page but no get / .

Comment: Using the 0.0.0.0 binding seemed to make a slight difference if i run the code with ruby.  I can then see the Sinatra 'welcome' page but no get / .  Using rackup nothing but some errors.  I might have a problem with ruby itself and am considering asking in another post.  I have the path /.rvm/rubies/ruby/2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/... Is that normal? I think site_ruby is for global addons, but why would 2.4.0 be in a 2.4.1 directory.

Comment: What if you just try the code instead of binding to all up addresses out side of vagrant. I assume that works. If so, I'm not familiar with vagrant but that path looks fun. You can always try 'rvm implode'